# Selecting all items in ListView works only once

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, selectall

I have a check box which will select all items in the ListView using a checkbox in each row.The code for the listener:

```
    check_all.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean checked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(checked==true)
            {   
                checkAll=true;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else if(checked==false)
            {
                clearAll=true;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    });
```

I also used setNotifyOnChange and set it true:

```
     final CheckAdapter adapter=new CheckAdapter(this,R.layout.layout_row,R.id.movie_name,arr);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

This is the code from the Adaptr's getView method concerning the checkbox:

```
        if(checkAll)
        {   
            watched.list.clear();
            holder.cb.setChecked(true);
        }
        if(clearAll)
            holder.cb.setChecked(false);
        holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean checked) {
                button.setChecked(checked);
                RelativeLayout parent=(RelativeLayout)button.getParent();
                TextView textView=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.movie_name);
                String name=textView.getText().toString();
                Log.d("CheckListActivity", "Movie "+name+" has been checked to "+checked);
                MovieCheck checkFlick=new MovieCheck(name,checked);
                if(checked)
                {
                    watched.addToList(checkFlick);
                }
                else
                {
                    watched.removeFromList(checkFlick);
                }
            }
        });
```

I would like to be able to turn the Select All on and off as I like but currently it only works once.

EDIT:Solved with the help of the comment.

```
    check_all.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean checked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(checked==true)
            {   
                checkAll=true;
                clearAll=false;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else if(checked==false)
            {
                checkAll=false;
                clearAll=true;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    });
```

Thank you  Poovizhirajan.N

Comment: in else part u again given as checkAll=true

Comment: solved.i had to change both parameters according to the situation while the checkbox is checked and unchecked.

Comment: CAN I POST MY ANSWER>?

Comment: yeah,please post your answer

Comment: just add one more parameter in adapter as Boolean Ex.MyAdapter adapter=new Save_Weight_Adapter(this, R.layout.layoutname, array,false);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

At no point do you reset the variables clearAll or checkAll to false, so after you've clicked the box twice both of getView's if statements will always be entered.

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```
if(checked==true)
{   
    checkAll=true;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
else if(checked==false)
{
    clearAll=false;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

thank you